# Distinguish name of a person vs of an organization

Tags: text, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Given the display name from the From: header of an email, I'd like to determine whether that represents the name of a person or something else.  Something else might often be the name of an organization, or perhaps a title/role.

Some examples:

- Alice Smith => name of a person
- Google Inc. => not the name of a person (it's an organization)
- Amazon Customer Support => not the name of a person (it's a title/role)
- Director of Engineering => not the name of a person (it's a title/role)

How can I recognize whether the sender's name represents the name of an individual?

---

One possible approach is to use machine learning and train a classifier.  But if I do that, what features should I use?  I've been reading the literature and haven't found anyone who has tackled exactly this issue, though I've seen some features that were used for related problems:

- A phrase of the form "Word Word" or "Word, Word" or "Word, Word Letter" or "Word Letter Word" or "Word, Word Letter." or "Word Letter. Word" are more likely to be a name (think "First Last" and "Last, First" and "Last, First MI" and "First MI Last").
- A phrase that starts with a title (Mr., Mrs., Miss, Ms., Dr., Prof., Lt., Sgt., etc.) is more likely to be a name.  A phrase that ends with a common name-suffix (Jr., Sr., Phd, Esq) is more likely to be a name.  A phrase that ends with a company indicator (Inc., Corp., Corporation) is likely not a name (it's probably an organization).
- It's possible to download a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1803628/781723) of the most common first names and last names from the US Census.  If the phrase contains one of those strings, it's more likely to be a name.  Or, one can use an existing lexicon, e.g., the BaLIE or Oak lexicons.
- If the phrase contains a word found in the dictionary, it's more likely to be not a name (e.g., an organization/title/role).
- If a word in the name matches a word in the domain name of the corresponding email address, it's more likely to be not a name of a person (e.g., Paypal Customer Service ).
- If a word contains an internal apostrophe or hyphen, it's more likely to be a name of a person (e.g., O'Connor, Jean-Claude).

But I don't know what will actually work.  What features should I use?  Alternatively, are there any pre-trained classifiers or any experience reports that describes what works?

I've read a bit about named entity recognition, but that seems like a harder problem.

Comment: You can use NER, its not hard. You can check: Point 5 - Named Entity Recognition - http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [OpenNLP NER](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.recognition) A lot of support is already out there.

They have these pre-trained models for names,organizations, locations etc.,
[here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/)

[this blog](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-tutorial.html) can get you started and pace up things for you.

Pre-trained models of OpenNLP worked very well for me.It is trained in US/UK names, so it must work for you. Also it is context based. It recognizes Mr. X eventhough the model doesn't know the name X because of the salutation.

It recognized organizations very well for me. you can train your own model once you have good training data(15000 sentences for good results). and the process for training is well explained in the blog i've mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first link is down, here is the archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20170502061628/https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.recognition